# Qual a forma correta de se instalar o LAMPP?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, ubuntu

Comecei a usar Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) recentemente e já me deparei com muitas dificuldades.

Então, tentei algumas vezes instalar a pilha lampp no Ubuntu e não consegui êxito. Sempre dava algum erro. E quero saber qual a forma correta de se instalar cada um, no caso, o apache, mysql e php, nas versões mais recentes. O problema é que eu andei instalando e desinstalando pacotes. E está um pouco bagunçado. O Que devo fazer? Como remover a bagunça e instalar tudo denovo com a melhor maneira possível para dar certo?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`

Comment: Consegui instalar. achei o link https://websiteforstudents.com/installing-apache2-mariadb-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04-with-php-7-2-support-lamp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

O Linux não é como windows que lida com registros (regedit) :-). As coisas não ficam bagunçadas, no máximo poderão haver bibliotecas orfãs e isso se resolve... Leia este url : https://www.diolinux.com.br/2013/07/emovendo-bibliotecas-e-dependencias-obsoletas-no-ubuntu.html

Se você esta passando por problemas de instalação, eu aconselho fazer um upgrade de Ubuntu para a ultima verssão.

Uma outra dica é, se você for usar o micro pra desenvolver, instale o Fedora 64 Bits.

Abçs.

Comment: Irei seguir o Conselho. Obg